# Ruby, Sinatra and Closing Connections

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Does anyone know if there is a way to prevent Sinatra from sending the 'Connection: close' header in its responses?

To be clear, I have a very simple

```
get '/path' do
  puts "Some (~200 byte long) string"
end
```

But, after looking at the output in a network analyser, I see it's sending the `Connection: close` header right after the `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, which I'd like to stop!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah ha! It seems Mongrel, the server my Sinatra app was running on, doesn't support Keep-Alive. so I just did:

```
set :server, 'thin'
```

after `gem install thin` and everything seems to be working better!

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak Ruby at all, and the Sinatra site isn't terribly clear on what it is (is it a framework for Ruby?) so I might be completely off my rocker here, but:

`Connection: close` is sent by your Web server when keep alives are turned off.  For scalability reasons, keep alives are generally considered to be step one on *things to turn off in your server*.  To be fair, there's a school of thought both ways, particularly when Ajax is involved.

I use nginx for my Django work (I'm thinking it's similar), and I have keep-alives turned off in nginx like this:

```
14:58 jsmith@lateralus% grep alive /etc/nginx/nginx.conf                            ~
     keepalive_timeout 0;
```

Apache uses KeepAlive (see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalive)).

If Sinatra is its own Web server, I can't find any documentation to turn keep alives on, and I'll go ahead and eat the fact that I look like an idiot.

Comment: No idiots here trust me, its supposed to be very simple to use but I just can't seem to figure it out! Sinatra is a framework that can run on any number of servers, I'm currently using it with mongrel (built into Ruby) so I guess I need to go there and hunt down some answers!

Comment: @JP: Then yes, look for information on keep alives in Mongrel's documentation.  I'm looking now and I'll revise the answer if I find something.